# Capturing signal strength per packet while associated to an ad-hoc network

Tags: routes, libpcap, wifi, ad-hoc-network

I am implementing an ad-hoc routing protocol and would like the ability to capture the associated signal strength (in terms of RSSI or SNR) on a per-packet basis.

I have been able to achieve this in monitor mode, however I will need to be able to do this while still being associated to the ad-hoc network.

Is this possible using such libraries as libpcap, or alternative WiFi hardware?

Many thanks.